# Как удалить дублирующиеся строки и в оставшейся строке заменить значение поля

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема заключается вот в чем, мне нужно удалить все дублирующиеся строки, и в оставшейся строке заменить поля, максимальными значениями из удаленных дублирующихся строк

Comment: Тогда сначала обновите ВСЕ строки-дубликаты, а потом уже удаляйте.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример - скрипты CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO с примером данных и требуемый результат для таких данных. также укажите точную версию MySQL.